# What updates should I install on a HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2008-r2, hp-proliant

Could someone suggest what do I need to install on a HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8 from the screenshot below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we update HP software we do all of it.  We'll update drivers and firmware together and make sure our server OS is up-to-date as well.  Is this the latest support pack?  It looks like you've already got all of the important stuff updated.  Take a look at the details of the items its suggesting you update and see if they're recommended and why.